# mysql version 5.0.95 and concat issues

Tags: mysql

I have the following query running under Mysql Version 5.0.95 - I cannot change the server as it is under company's descition when to upgrade

trying to run it

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE UPPER(CONCAT_WS(' ', `firstname`, `lastname`) LIKE UPPER('%Test User%')
```

and getting this error

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Comment: This isn't a version-specific issue -- it's a simple syntax error. You are missing a right parenthesis before `LIKE`.

Comment: damm man, this is nuts, what a mistake, THanks answer accepted